# Can I print HTML as it would be viewed in a web page without tags in python?

Tags: python, printing, html

I want to print html to a document but I want it formatted as it would be viewed in a web page.

I have the following code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html = """
<B>THIS IS A TABLE</B>
</div>

<center>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="font-size: 10pt; margin-top: 6pt; ">

<tr style="font-size: 7pt;">
    <td colspan="2" align="left" nowrap><B>THIS IS A HEADER1</B></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" nowrap><B> THIS IS A HEADER2</B></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" nowrap><B> THIS IS A HEADER3</B></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" nowrap><B> THIS IS A HEADER4</B></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(html))

tmp.open('tmp.txt','w')
tmp.write(soup)
tmp.close()
```

But this prints out the html with tags.  Any way to do this in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you really *do* want to write this as a text file, you could look into using [lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) as a renderer for html to text.

If you just want to be able to open the html file you wrote and have it appear exactly as it would in a web browser, I suggest saving it as `tmp.html` and opening it with a web browser.

Comment: I could just save this as an html file and open it in a web browser, but I am going to be adding thousands of these tables to a document and I'd rather be able to open them all up in one text document.

Comment: Now that I think about it, this will work great by just saving it as an html file and opening it in a web browser.  I should be able to just append all the tables to the html file and open to view them all at once in the web browser.  Thank you!  Sometimes its the simple answer that's the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
tmp.write(cgi.escape(soup.renderContents()))
```

Comment: This didn't work.  It gave me the following in the tmp file:  &lt;b&gt;THIS IS A TABLE&lt;/b&gt;

&lt;center&gt;
&lt;table width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="font-size: 10pt; margin-top: 6pt; "&gt;
&lt;tr style="font-size: 7pt;"&gt;
&lt;td colspan="2" align="left" nowrap="nowrap"&gt;&lt;b&gt;THIS IS A HEADER1&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td colspan="3" align="center" nowrap="nowrap"&gt;&lt;b&gt; THIS...

Comment: So what do you want exactly? A nice *HTML* representation of HTML source code or? Please be specific!

Comment: Yes, I want it to be viewed exactly as it would be viewed if opened in a webpage, if possible.